# Exception caught by gesture: Stack Overflow

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-provider, gesturedetector

Every time I tap on the ListView Card this error shows 'Exception caught by gesture: Stack Overflow" as seen on this screenshot(https://www.screencast.com/t/udA8NZZ1AqsD)

The problem here is somewhere in the Gesturedetector's onTap code

List of Screenshots
Default Navigation PageRoute -> https://www.screencast.com/t/qKZQgaraFi
With Just a Plain text called 'test' -> https://www.screencast.com/t/XOxGkANLZEjC
Slightly changed Navigation Page Route -> https://www.screencast.com/t/1F82pyQtQ2v9
Gesturedetector with new additional code -> https://www.screencast.com/t/hRefONV3o
Code that passes data from firebase -> https://www.screencast.com/t/24gc9zqfxmGX

Result Link:
Result #1 -> https://www.screencast.com/t/PmiC5U6S2L
Result #2 -> https://www.screencast.com/t/udA8NZZ1AqsD

I have tried the following below

TRY 1
Tried the default Navigation Page Route and the Gesturedetector is working fine. The downside is I can only show text(see the link above With Just a Plain text called 'test') and can't pass data using the provider package flutter as seen on this screenshot

Default Navigation PageRoute

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductDetail()));
  },
)
```

With Just a Plain text called 'test'

```
Text(
 'test',
 style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 35.0,
    color: Colors.black45,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
  ),
),
```

Result: see Result #1

TRY 2
Tried the slightly changed Navigation Page Route(see the link 'Slightly changed Navigation Page Route' above) together with the ordinary text(see the link above = With Just a Plain text called 'test')

Navigation PageRoute

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute (builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ProductDetail();
    })
  );
},
```

With Just a Plain text called 'test'

```
Text(
  'test',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 35.0,
    color: Colors.black45,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
  ),
),
```

Result: see Result #1

TRY 3
Tried it with a new additional code(see link above 'Gesturedetector with new additional code') together with the ordinary text(see the link above With Just a Plain text called 'test')

Navigation PageRoute

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTap: () {
    itemNotifier.currentProditem = itemNotifier.itemList[index];
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute (builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return ProductDetail();
      })
    );
  },
),
```

With Just a Plain text called 'test'

```
Text(
  'test',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 35.0,
    color: Colors.black45,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
  ),
),
```

Result: see Result #2

TRY 4
Tried it with a new additional code(see link above 'Gesturedetector with new additional code') together with a code that passes data from firebase(see link above 'Code that passes data from firebase')

Code that Passes data from Firebase

```
Text(
  (itemNotifier.currentProditem.price),
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 35.0,
    color: Colors.black45,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
  ),
),
```

Result: see Result #2

My Code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ItemNotifier itemNotifier = Provider.of<ItemNotifier>(context);
    return new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffdcdcdc),
        appBar: new AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: new Text(
              'Discover Products',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 26.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF352d5a)
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: itemNotifier.itemList.length == null ? 0 : itemNotifier.itemList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                      onTap: () {
                       itemNotifier.currentProditem = itemNotifier.itemList[index];
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute (builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return ProductDetail();
                            })
                        );
                        // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductDetail()));
                      },
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40.0, 5.0, 20.0, 5.0),
                            height: 140.0,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                  100.0, 10.0, 20.0, 20.0),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                        .spaceBetween,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                        .start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                            .spaceBetween,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            (itemNotifier.itemList[index].price),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 24.0,
                                                color: Colors.black45,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          IconButton(
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                                            color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              setState(() {
                                                print('Go to Favorites');
                                              });
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                       Container(
                                          width: 280.0,
                                          child: Text(
                                            (itemNotifier.itemList[index].producttitle),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 24.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                            ),
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            maxLines: 1,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 5.0,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    width: 280.0,
                                    child: Text(
                                      (itemNotifier.itemList[index].description),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey
                                      ),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            left: 20.0,
                            top: 15.0,
                            bottom: 15.0,
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black26,
                                      offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0),
                                      blurRadius: 6.0,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                  child: Image(
                                    width: 110.0,
                                    image: AssetImage(
                                        'image'
                                    ),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                  );
                }
            ),
          ),
        );

  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate all the details but unfortunately I got lost... definitively you seem to have a loop somewhere. Seeing the stacktrace... it points to `itemNotifier.currentProditem = itemNotifier.itemList[index];`... but not sure how a loop is generated there.

Comment: Can you add code for your ItemNotifier?

Comment: @Tanuj   `class ItemNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Proditem> _itemList = [];
  Proditem _currentProditem;

  UnmodifiableListView<Proditem> get itemList => UnmodifiableListView(_itemList);

  Proditem get currentProditem => _currentProditem;

  set itemList(List<Proditem> itemList) {
    _itemList = itemList;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set currentProditem(Proditem proditem) {
    currentProditem = proditem;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}` or you can check the screenshot here https://www.screencast.com/t/JUjv8ZYxMOYr

Comment: @ClaudioRedi you can check the itemNotifier here https://www.screencast.com/t/JUjv8ZYxMOYr

Comment: May I know the reason why do you want to update `itemNotifier.currentProditem = itemNotifier.itemList[index] ` with this?

Comment: @Tanuj My goal here is to get the data from the selected list view card to reflect it to the details page of the item. for example, one list view card contains the title 'Sushi', if that list card is pressed it goes to the details page and it will say 'Sushi' if on the otherhand the list view card contains 'Hotdog', when pushed on details page it will say hotdog.

Comment: @Tanuj by the way this is for an eCommerce site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're recursively calling the set method again inside the set method (hence the stack overflow)

```
set currentProditem(Proditem proditem){
   currentProditem = proditem; //forgot the underscore,
   // it should be _currentProditem = proditem;
   // To change the variables not the setter again
   notifylisteners();
}
```

Comment: OMG! it worked! I completely forgot that underscore at currentProditem. Thank you Thank you so much for your help.